# Canonical Competitive Sports in Pathfinder

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-2e, world-building, golarion, culture

I've been looking around the online resources to find some sort of list of competitive sports that may be played by citizens in the Age of Lost Omens.

A full, digital list would be great. Bonus points for non-violent, athletic sports that would be popular for chaotic societies, such as a Goblin settlement.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think a comprehensive exists, but there are many sports whose popularity we can safely infer:

- **javelin throw**: Kurgess is supposed to be the demigod of sports and competition, and his favored weapon is the javelin. On top of that his adepts, in Pathfinder 1, had access to [a feat that let them throw javelins further](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/traits/combat-traits/strong-arm-supple-wrist/). It would be very unlikely that this sport wasn't at least a little popular among Kurgess' cult.
- **kite-battle**: practiced during the Gala of Sails and the Kraken Carnival. (according to [pathfinderwiki](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Holidays_and_festivals))
- **archery**: at least during [Archer's Day](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Archer%27s_Day), Erastil's yearly festival
- **swimming**: during [Silverglazer Sunday](https://pathfinderwiki.com/wiki/Silverglazer_Sunday)
- **race while being chased by raptors**: not sure how competitive this one is, but the Running of the Raptors is a Kurgess festival where some people do that (voluntarily). No doubt goblins would be interested.
- **magic hacking**: during the Breaching Festival in Korvosa, people try to break through the Academy's magical protections. Not sure how competitive this is.

On top of that there are the classical gladiatoral duels (with a degree of violence ranging from "only for the show" to "deadly"), with or without weapons, with magic...

Comment: +1. Tarnbreakers Trail (a PFS scenario) features competitive racing also.

Comment: Is anyone aware if the Lost Omens Travel Guide adds any? I've not got my hands on it yet.

Comment: Don't forget games. Chess players consider their game a sport too, if played competitively.

Comment: @Anne Aunyme - Some good options, thank you!

Comment: @ESCE - I was thinking about the Travel Guide and I searched a few times on Google/2e.aonprd and couldn't find anything, really. But seeing you ask the question prompted me to look further. I found a preview video on YouTube and it looks like there are some sports, such as "log rolling" (pg 59) and "Basilisk" (pg 61-62). Basilisk looks almost exactly what I had in mind, as it seems to be inspired by rugby. Unfortunately, I cannot find any pages for these on AoN.

Comment: @AustinBrown no worries, I'm sure someone has it. I might be getting it this weekend myself, in which case I can update the answer. I've heard very good things about it. Alternatively, a lot of people on the subreddit have access to this book - asking over there for sports listed in the Travel Guide is sure to get you a response eventually. They're at https://www.reddit.com/r/pathfinder2e.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin I haven't seen references for chess being played competitively in Golarion. Maybe I missed one: after all I haven't skimmed all the official campaigns and PFS scenarios that exist

Comment: @AnneAunyme I mean whatever intellectual games are played in that world, could be considered sports too. (I do not know the game world, and have no idea if chess would be played there, I just used it as an example from our world):

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin pretty much any sports we can think of could have an equivalent in Golarion, at least in some remote place. That said, the question is about canonical sports, not sports that may or may not be practiced there. AFAIK Chess is not canonical as a sport in Golarion, because the books don't state it is, but if some GM wants to put a chess tournament in their game, why not?

Comment: Kickball is mentioned in the Strength of Thousands AP and "sports sticks" are mentioned as a possession of one of the students, whatever that means.

Comment: This might be a good candidate to convert to a community wiki answer